# property of sum in floating point arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, proof-verification, floating-point

define the set of floating point numbers by $F(2,53,-1022,1023)$.

A Sum $(a+b)$ with $a,b \in F$ is said to be **good** if $(a+b)\in F$ otherwise it is a **bad** sum.
I have to figure out if there are more **bad** or **good** sums.

My attempt : Since $F$ is finite it has a maximum element call it $M$. Now i fix $M$ and form the sums of $x+M$ for all $x\in F$. Each of this sum will not be in the set because it is bigger then it's maximum value. Also there are $n$ such sums  (all different from each other) , where $n$ is the number of elements in $F$. So the number of **bad** sums is at least $n$ , while the number of **good** sums can be at most $n$.

This is an old exam question and the solution to the problem is totally different to mine ( it depends on the parameters of the set while my argument is general) so i would like to know if my reasoning is ok or if not , where does it fail? Thank you for the feedback!

Ps: If you have troubles with understanding the notation please let me know and i will try to improve the question , thanks.

Comment: If you are not using a totally unusual definition of a floating point system, where will be negative numbers and not all $x+M$ will be greater than $M$. The situation when the sum is $> M$ is normally called **overflow** and if it is less the smallest number is called **underflow**. But these are not the only situations which produce *bad numbers*, e.g. $2^{30}+2^{-30}$ does not produce overflow or underflow but it is not $\in F$ (and will be rounded to the nearest element of $F$ in actual implementations).

Comment: @gammatester Yes i know that , i wanted to build a general and easy proof of the statement but i was wrong since i considered only the number ofdifferent **good** sums , while i had to count all **good** sums , that's where i failed i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your notation, but your proof contains the claim that "the number of good sums can be at most $n$", which is incorrect.  If $F$ were the interval $[1,100]$, then indeed there are $99$ sums $1+100, 2+100,\ldots, 99+100$ all of which are bad.  However there are ${50\choose 2}=1225$ sums of two distinct numbers each in $[1,50]$, which are all good.

Comment: I thought i had to look for the number of different **good** sums ( that's why at most $n$ sums), but that wasn't the case. Thanks for your help.